# how do i fetch data by id on react native (rest api)

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, crud

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react- 
native';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: true
};
}

async getMovies() {
try {
  const response = await 
fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json');
  const json = await response.json();
  this.setState({ data: json.movies });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} finally {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false });
}
}

componentDidMount() {
this.getMovies();
}

render() {
const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
    {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
        )}
      />
    )}
  </View>
  );
 }
 };
```

this is the api
{
"title": "The Basics - Networking",
"description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
"movies": [
{ "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
{ "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
{ "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
{ "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
{ "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
]
}

I want this code to fetch and show data by id. just like the query show movies by id.

This is the result.

[image: this is the result]

I try to fetch data with id 1 but i dont know how to do it. i dont know how to show  it to react native. and i dont know how fetch the data by id

Comment: Please include the code directly in the question instead of in a picture please.

Comment: im sorry, how do i upload the code. im beginner

Comment: You can edit your question and either use the `{}` button to add code or create a snippet via the `<>` button.

Comment: Didn't get your question do you want to display the list in a sorted manner or is it something else? let me know

Comment: I want to display its data by id. so, for example, the data that I display id =1 then only title:star wars, release year : 1977 will appear. im sorry English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I pass a parameter like this:

my call to the API:

```
const getDetails = (id) => { 
   return api.Get(`/api/details/${id}`);
}
```

then  in the react code

```
const getInfo = async(e) => {
  apiCall.GetDetails(value to be passed here)

 }
```

Comment: is this for react native also?

Comment: this is javascript, so yes